# Jquery show hide doesn't work on mobile at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on small russian project and i need a help with mobile version of my site 
php8098.github.io/breakfast

The problem's in first slider on the play buttton, it must open modal window
please help me i need to fix this bug before tommorow, and im sorry if i write my question like a very stupid man

Here's jquery code

```
$('.button-play-1').on("click", function(){
    $('.video-popup-1').show()
    });
    $('.close-1').on("click", function(){
    $('.video-popup').hide()
    });
```

here's html

```
           <div class="feedback-slider">
                <div class="feedback-slide feedback-slide-1">
                    <button class="button-play button-play-1">
                    <img src="img/play.png" alt="">
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="feedback-slide feedback-slide-2">
                    <button class="button-play button-play-2">
                    <img src="img/play.png" alt="">
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="feedback-slide feedback-slide-3">
                    <button class="button-play button-play-3">
                    <img src="img/play.png" alt="">
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="feedback-slide feedback-slide-4">
                    <button class="button-play button-play-4">
                    <img src="img/play.png" alt="">
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="feedback-slide feedback-slide-5">
                    <button class="button-play button-play-5">
                    <img src="img/play.png" alt="">
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="feedback-slide feedback-slide-6">
                    <button class="button-play button-play-6">
                    <img src="img/play.png" alt="">
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.feedback-slider -->
        <div class="video-popup video-popup-1">
        <div class="popup">
            <iframe width="380" height="403" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/B3DP2rwQmpI" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            <div class="close close-1">
            <img src="img/close.png" alt=""></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

here's css

```
.video-popup {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 8;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
.popup {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 7%;
  width: 420px;
  height: 550px;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.popup iframe {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: -10px;
  top: -15px;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 300;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 10px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  background-color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Did a quick test, it works. Did you put your jQuery code inside `$(function(){---code here---});` to make sure it's only executed when document is ready?

Comment: I have this function

Comment: Hey, just register your click events after the `slick` initialization of the feedback sections

Comment: I try it but its not working

Comment: That's very strange, in firefox mobile view, the click doesn't work indeed, but manually registering the click event in dev console make it work again. Anything de-registering the events? (Which i assumed .slick() was causing this)

Comment: You should try `$('.section-feedback').on('click', '.button-play-1', function() { $('.video-popup-1').show(); })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the same issue, My IOS device was not able to detect click on button or icon.

So I try to inline attribute `onclick` .

like

`<button class="button-play button-play-1" onclick="$('.video-popup-1').show();">`
try this, might help :)

PS: this was the only one solution I found when, I faced this issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you helped me